# get_category_parents for custom post type taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, categories

I know that we can get the parent category in normal post type by:

```
get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' &raquo; ');
```

But how can we get the parent category in custom post type?

I use this for:

```
if ( is_category() || is_single() && !is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) { // Full path links 
    $category = get_the_category();
    $ID = $category[0]->cat_ID;
    echo '<li>'.get_category_parents( $ID, TRUE, '', FALSE ).'</li>';       
} elseif ( is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) {
    $category = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio-category' );
    $ID = $category[0]->cat_ID;
    echo '<li>'.get_category_parents( $ID, TRUE, '', FALSE ).'</li>';
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I want to display the parent category of the portfolio post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated answer:*

There's now a core [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_parents_list/) since WordPress 4.8, to list the ancestors of a given term:

```
get_term_parents_list( 
    int $term_id, 
    string $taxonomy, 
    string|array $args = array() 
)
```

and [`get_category_parents()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L44) is a wrapper for that function with `$taxonomy` as `'category'`.

**Previous answer:**

Here is a modified version I made from the function `get_category_parents()` to support general taxonomies.

```
/**
 * Retrieve category parents with separator for general taxonomies.
 * Modified version of get_category_parents()
 *
 * @param int $id Category ID.
 * @param string $taxonomy Optional, default is 'category'. 
 * @param bool $link Optional, default is false. Whether to format with link.
 * @param string $separator Optional, default is '/'. How to separate categories.
 * @param bool $nicename Optional, default is false. Whether to use nice name for display.
 * @param array $visited Optional. Already linked to categories to prevent duplicates.
 * @return string
 */
function wpse85202_get_taxonomy_parents( $id, $taxonomy = 'category', $link = false, $separator = '/', $nicename = false, $visited = array() ) {

            $chain = '';
            $parent = get_term( $id, $taxonomy );

            if ( is_wp_error( $parent ) )
                    return $parent;

            if ( $nicename )
                    $name = $parent->slug;
            else
                    $name = $parent->name;

            if ( $parent->parent && ( $parent->parent != $parent->term_id ) && !in_array( $parent->parent, $visited ) ) {
                    $visited[] = $parent->parent;
                    $chain .= wpse85202_get_taxonomy_parents( $parent->parent, $taxonomy, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited );
            }

            if ( $link )
                    $chain .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $parent,$taxonomy ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $parent->name ) ) . '">'.$name.'</a>' . $separator;
            else
                    $chain .= $name.$separator;

            return $chain;
    }
```

You can use the function like this:

```
echo wpse85202_get_taxonomy_parents($cat, $tax, TRUE, ' &raquo; ');
```

or like

```
echo wpse85202_get_taxonomy_parents(65, 'country', TRUE, ' &raquo; ');
```

Comment: @MattR thanks for your edit, first I accepted it, as I got confused about the word "nicename" for a moment, but it should be nice in the slug-way, so I reverted it again ;-) I also updated the answr with the new core function in 4.8.